# Filling a tableview with firebase database and storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I've got a tableview I'm wanting to fill with firebase data and also an image that I'm storing in storage.

My initial gameplan was to run an observer to firebase, and for each item in the snapshot, populate a firebase data array and pull data from storage with that same snap name and put it in another array that would both match up, and then in my cell, I'd fill the image with the indexpath.row of the image array, and data from the data array, and it'd match up and be cool.

This crash and burned because downloading images from storage I guess is taking longer than pulling information? and the images array is being filled slower than the data so I'm getting a crash that the image[indexPath.row] is out of range.

What's the correct way of going about filling a tableview with data from the database and storage?

Edit:

My firebase data looks like :

```
users
  02938409283049829304
    Category
        Cats : true
        Dogs:  true
```

This is what I was trying to do :

```
REF_USERS.child(currentUserUID).child("Category").observeEventType(.Value) { ( snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        self.categoriesArray = []
        self.imagesArray = []

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {


                self.categoryArray.append(snap.key)


                let pictureRef = DataService.ds.REF_BASE_STORAGE.child(self.currentUserUID).child(String(snap.key))

                pictureRef.dataWithMaxSize(9809898999098098 /* no idea what to put here*/) { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print(error)  

                    } else {
                         let picture : UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)

                       self.imagesArray.append(picture)

                        print(self.imagesArray.count)

                    }
                }


self.tableView.reloadData()
```

So how I wanted that to read was :

Go to a user and look under their categories. I'm looking to post the name of it, so I just use the key. The key name is exactly the same as the image when it's saved into storage, so I use that key name to grab the photo from storage.

```
 let pictureRef = DataService.ds.REF_BASE_STORAGE.child(self.currentUserUID).child(String(snap.key))
```

I add the data from the database to an array and the images from storage to another array, then when I'm making the cell I just set the data to data[indexPath.row] and image to images[indexPath.row]. When I do images.count and data.count and I have 3 things in both, I images getting to 3 lags behind, so that's where I get the images[indexPath.row] out of range error I guess.

Comment: There really isn't a correct way; there's several paths to follow. A lot of it depends on your Firebase structure for your data and images. Can you include that in your question as text?

Comment: @Jay Yep it's there now. I don't know if I'm way off base with doing it that way. I'm only going to be showing users like a max of 10 photos at a time so I figured I may not need to deal with a cache? Any guidance is appreciated , thank ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually load images asynchronously and I have a delegate method that fires when download is complete and will refresh the tableview when new data/image is downloaded.

Making a placeholder image and maybe with a spinning loader icon would be great to display before the images get's downloaded.

Edit:

You need to call self.tableview.reload() in the pictureRef.dataWithMaxSize method. 
Since the download is async your tableview will now reload when the method REF_USERS.child is complete and not necessarily when the image is downloaded. 
So either place self.tableview.reloadData in your else claus in pictureRef.dataWithMaxSize or make a delegate method in the very same spot to handle finished downloaded images.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Was gonna mess around with this and come back with a comment if I couldn't figure it out but your edit did the trick. Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Comment: Just one last quick question. With the way my code is set up atm, every time a new post is made I guess the pictures are being redownloaded, so the entiretableview has to repopulate so it's very slow and clunky looking vs just a new post being added in by its own. 

Is this where a cache comes in? (never done that before) or could I just call an initial .Value observer and then user a .childAdded? How would you tackle that?

Comment: It's not good to fill the entire tableview every time a image is downloaded. When you have an array of data to populate the tableview call .reload. When you need to add items, such as images that is downloaded async, or other items that need to be added later, it would be good to just insert the items at row, rather than filling the tableview over and over again. But you should always add your items/data to the tableview array, because the system may refresh the tableview on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the best way you could do this, is show placeholder images, or a loading icon for every image your calling from the database. As the images come in, you update the tableView accordingly.

Another way you can do this, is run the request asynchronously, and as soon as all the processes finish, you show all the images together.

You can even show a loading screen and let the images load before you display the tableView.

All you have to do is ensure that the images exist before you start adding them to the tableView, and make sure that memory usage doesn't go overboard.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll probably end up using a mix and match of everyone's answer. Appreciate the help